# How can I pipe tsharks output in realtime to c# program

Tags: c#, .net, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark

Like the title says, I am wondering how I can output tshark(wireshark command line) packets directly to my c# application.

I would like to output the packets so I can process the individual packets in my application.

For instance redirect output, and add a callback to handle each packet and then process each individual packet.

Could anyone with similar experience or even any idea how to do this help me out? It would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-l` option of [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html). From the documentation:

> -l
>
> [....]
>
> This may be useful when piping the output of TShark to another
>   program, as it means that the program to which the output is piped
>   will see the dissected data for a packet as soon as TShark sees the
>   packet and generates that output, rather than seeing it only when the
>   standard output buffer containing that data fills up.